# How does it make sense to 'edify saints'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This example sentence is under the [definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/edify?q=edify) proper:

> Some are called to sow, others to reap some are eminently qualified to awaken sinners, others to edify saints.

Don't saints, by definition, outshine and transcend the need  to be "Instruct[ed] or improve[d] (someone) morally or intellectually" ?

Original Source: [Miscellanies of Rev Thomas E Peck](http://books.google.com/books?id=gZlAAAAAYAAJ&q=%22others+to+edify+saints%22&dq=%22others+to+edify+saints%22&sa=X&ei=0dnAU92KNM7OkwWrq4HIDw&redir_esc=y), 1895

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about theology more than about the English Language. Whether a saint is born as such or becomes one through his path in life seems to depend very little on the language we use to talk about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As oerkelens said, this is more about theology than English. But it is worth pointing out that: some theologians use *saint* to mean any believer, living or dead; some use it to mean any departed soul, on the assumption that any Christian is now in Heaven; and almost any would regard the idea that any human being, living or dead, is so perfect as to be beyond improvement as either idolatrous or blasphemous.

(And no, I am not interested in a theological discussion, whether in comments or in chat; try Christianity.SE if your research does not help.)

Answer (score 2):

( Based on the exerpt provided)I think what's meant here by "to edify saints"is "to instruct people who are on the path to sainthood", bring people to enlighment, *make* saints.